# Fixed navbar is overlapping other elements

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a fixed navbar on my website, but it overlaps other elements. As you can see from the snippet, `<nav>` is supposed to be the navbar, and `<div>` is meant to be some other content on the website. `<div>` element needs to be on space outside navbar like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLXEY.png

I already know about `margin-left` method, but my navbar doesn't have a specified width, so that method wouldn't work, and plus I'm looking for a more efficient way to solve this.

```css
nav {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2cm;
  position: fixed;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

nav a {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
</nav>
<div>
  <h1>Sample text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create an example, for support text at center i add class call page:

```css
nav {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2cm;
  position: fixed;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
}

nav a {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  display: block;
}

.page{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    background-color: #F4F7FA;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-bottom: 50px
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
</nav>
<div class='page'>
  <h1>Sample text</h1><br>
  <p>Another element</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the `margin` fix is the simplest option, you can use the `position: sticky;` CSS property on the sidebar.

Have a look at this [JSFidde](https://jsfiddle.net/75tez84w/1/) I wrote.